# Extract and clean 'resendential address' using regex from OCR output of bill scans

Tags: python, regex

I am attempting to find, extract and clean addresses in a scan of a bill. Addresses begin with string like 'Address: | address | etc. ' and end 4 numerics (postcodes).

Regex:

```py
possible_addresses = list(re.findall("^.ddress:[0-9]{4}", data))
```

Address: 10 LEWIS ST, BERRI SA 5343

Comment: I recommend trying your expressions at some interactive page like regex101, can help you detect mistakes easilu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the below code to work perfectly as I needed.

```
import re
data='Service address —_Unit8-10 LEWIS St, BERRI,SA 5343'
possible_addresses = re.search('address[\W_]*(.*?\d{4})', data,re.I)
address = possible_addresses[1]
print('Address : ' address)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the addresses occupy an entire line, we can try using the following regex pattern:

```
Address: (.* \d{4})
```

Script:

```
address = "10 LEWIS ST, BERRI SA 5343"
possible_addresses = re.findall(r'Address: (.* \d{4})', address)
print(possible_addresses)
```

If an address could span more than one line, or might share a given line with text other than an address, then use this pattern instead:

```
\bAddress: (.*? \d{4})\b
```

Comment: Thanks Tim! This works just like I expected it to. 

Sometimes I get special characters like _ or extra spaces in front. Is there a way to lose any such cases and consider alphanumeric to be the first character? 
Example: 
Got: [('', ' —_V9,11-17 Silver St, Chatswood,NSW 2067')]
Expected: [(''V9,11-17 Silver St, Chatswood,NSW 2067')]

Comment: I have a solution that works for now. Need to explore more options. 
address = str(possible_addresses[0])
    for k in address.split("\n"):
        print(re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", ' ', k))

Comment: Try using `re.findall(r'^[^A-Za-z0-9]*?(.*\d{4})', address)`

Comment: Thanks again for all the help Tim! I don't know if it is just me doing something wrong, but the above code is returning an empty list. The first one returns the result almost as expected except that it contains some special characters in front of the address.

Comment: I suggest that you open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this and comment if any edge case is left. I tested code below and it solves your problem. Hope it helps.

```
import re

statement = 'Address: house number 43, 56th street, 1234'

print(re.findall("^Address:[A-Za-z0-9, ]*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]", statement))
#['Address: house number 43, 56th street, 1234']
```